# convergence ( in measure theory)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does $g_n=n \mathcal{X_{[1/n,2/n]}}$  converge to g=0. Leb. measure

My idea is since the $[1/n,2/n]$ goes to zero as n goes to infinity, there is no element in the interval, so the charateristic function,$\mathcal{X}$ is zero.(pointwisely)

for uniformly?

is this reasoning correct?

Comment: "Convergence" in which sense?

Comment: pointwise and unifromly

Comment: Pointwise, yes, uniformly, no.

Comment: could you plase give some idea of how

Comment: Some idea? Well, for starters one could look at the definition (in your case, definitionS since you are interested in two modes of convergence).

Comment: is the reasonig i stated correct for pointwise convergence?

Comment: The result holds but the formulation of the reasoning is questionable (there **are** elements "in the interval", for every $n$).

Comment: another try: here the measure is Leb. so by def. of convergence in measure and Leb measure, we have $2/n-1/n=1/n$ which goes to zero, pointwisely. also it cannot go uniformly, since n near zero is infinity.

Comment: could you please comment on my last comment. is  it  true?

Comment: Still a confusing mess.  As suggested, start with the definition of convergence you want, and see if it is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $ x > 0$ then there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{2}{n} < x$ for all $n \geq N$. Hence $n \chi_{(1/n, 2/n)}(x) = 0$ for all $n \geq N$.